# Trying to use Three.js - ShaderMaterial in JSF page, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null

Tags: javascript, jsf, three.js

Based on a previous post using their code,
http://jsfiddle.net/XGWGn/118/, I am trying to place the code in the HTML pane into a JSF 2.1 page. I'm wondering if the contents of my JavaServer Face page is causing the following error in the JavaScript console:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of null

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
        <title>BYOS screen</title>
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="byos.css"/>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r71/three.js" type="text/javascript"/>

        <h:outputScript name="OrbitControls.js" library="js"/>

        <style>
            body {
                /* set margin to 0 and overflow to hidden, to use the complete page */
                margin: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <!-- Div which will hold the Output -->
        <div id="WebGL-output">
        </div>
        <div id="Stats-output">
        </div>

        <script src="./resources/js/06-mesh-properties-4-shader.js" type="text/javascript"/>
        <script id="vertex_shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

        varying vec2 vUv;
        varying vec3 vNormal;
        varying vec3 vViewPosition;

        void main() {

                vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

                vUv = uv;
                vNormal = normalize( normalMatrix * normal );
                vViewPosition = -mvPosition.xyz;

                gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

        }

        </script>

        <script id="fragment_shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

        uniform sampler2D texture;
        uniform sampler2D texture2;

        varying vec2 vUv;
        varying vec3 vNormal;
        varying vec3 vViewPosition;

        void main() {

                vec4 tColor = texture2D( texture, vUv );
                vec4 tColor2 = texture2D( texture2, vUv );

                // hack in a fake pointlight at camera location, plus ambient
                vec3 normal = normalize( vNormal );
                vec3 lightDir = normalize( vViewPosition );

                float dotProduct = max( dot( normal, lightDir ), 0.0 ) + 0.2;

                gl_FragColor = vec4( mix( tColor.rgb, tColor2.rgb, tColor2.a ), 1.0 ) * dotProduct;

        }

        </script>


    </h:body>
</html>
```

I am just trying to mess around with ShaderMaterial on JSF 2.1 page which is an Facelets file. The 3D shape is rendered correctly in the jsfiddle URL, but doesn't render at all in the JSF page.

Comment: How is this a jsf page? No h:head, h:body and only an h:outputscript tag. Did you check if that works? If it actually loads that script. Check your browser developer tool

Comment: Apologies, I must have accidentally undid some code before copying and pasting. Now the page has a warning message of
Error Traced[line: 1] The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

Comment: Have you tried copypasting the error message in a [search engine](https://google.com/search?q=%22The+processing+instruction+target+matching+%22%5BxX%5D%5BmM%5D%5BlL%5D%22+is+not+allowed.%22)?

Comment: Sorry, the last "[xX][mM][lL]" error I posted is resolved.

Comment: @ACoder: And? All OK now?

Comment: No - sorry I wasn't clear, the original error still exists in the original post.

Comment: Well then you are able to answer the questions in the first comment

Comment: Did you want me to convert all script elements into h:outputscript tags?

Comment: It seems like I can't change the script elements with types that are of "x-shader/x-vertex" or "x-shader/x-fragment" type to h:outputScript elements since by default the h:outputScript component is of type "text/javascript"; so nothing has changed regarding the original JavaScript error. Thank you for pointing that out though. I do need those JSF components in there.

Answer (score 0):

I put the 06-mesh-properties-4-shader.js (the js file containing the code in the jsFiddle JavaScript pane) as the last script element in the h:body element. Previously, the element with id="vertex_shader" wasn't loaded yet when the script was called; that's why the textContent property was null. It had nothing to do with it being in a JSF 2.1 page.